# Работа с memcached в ZF2

Tags: zend-framework-2, memcache

Как задать время жизни ключа в memcache?
Работаю с кешом примерно так:

```
$memcached = $sl->get('memcache');
$value = $memcached->getItem('key');
//логика приложения
$memcached->setItem('key', 'value');
```

В функции setItem отсутствуют дополнительные параметры, которые позволяют задать ttl.
По ключу memcache мне возвращается объект Memcache из storage. Правильно ли я понимаю, что это обертка над работой php-memcache. Если да, то как в зенде переключиться на php-memcached.

Answer (score 0):

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что это обертка над работой php-memcache.

Вы можеет узнать что означает memcache  в вашем контексте если посмотрите на свои конфиги, они скорее всего лежат в файле на подобии: `config/autoload/cache.local.php`. Но скорее всего вы правы. Хотя если мне не изменяет память адаптера для `memcache` из коробки не было, но я могу ошибаться.

> Если да, то как в зенде переключиться на php-memcached.

Чтобы изменить используемую библиотеку вам достаточно дополнить конфиг, и вызывать другой сервис у сервис локатора, или изменить старый конфиг, чтобы `memcache` был на самом деле алиасом для `memcached`, но это не очень явно, а значит не очень хорошо.

> В функции setItem отсутствуют дополнительные параметры, которые
>   позволяют задать ttl.

Да вы совершенно правы, зенд из коробки не позволяет установить время жизни для конкретной записи, затрудняюсь сказать с чем это связано, но, видимо, в целях совместимости. Ttl вы можете задать в конфиге. Возможно будет работать схема с изменнием ttl программно перед записью:

```
$cache->getOptions()->setTtl(3600);
```

Решение не очень очевидное, требующее к тому же возвращать ttl к исходному значению. Я бы вам советовал сделать отдельный конфиг для каждого из типов кеша.